# How to run ezstream on system startup?

Tags: sh, icecast

I installed icecast2 & ezstream on my Ubuntu 14.04 x64 server, but now I want to run ezstream on system startup. Icecast2 runs automatically when system starts.

Please, tell me how to do this. I need to start ezstream after icecast2 started.

P.S. I tried to put the command in rc.local, but it doesn't work for me:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/usr/bin/ezstream -c /root/ezstream_mp3.xml &

exit 0
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Mind elaborating on the "doesn't work for me" aspect? ezstream should have a log file, have you looked into it?

Comment: @TBR There's no log file for ezstream, I found only log file for icecast2, but icecast2 runs automatically and I can open admin of icecast2. So there's a problem in starting ezstream automatically. I installed clean server and installed icecast2 & ezstream, so it doesn't work for everyone I think... If I manually type in console "/usr/bin/ezstream -c /root/ezstream_mp3.xml" it works! But I don't want to type this everytime, I need to start it automatically.

Comment: That's only partly true. ezstream doesn't have a log file, but produces log output. Try running it as "/usr/bin/ezstream -c /root/ezstream_mp3.xml 2>&1 >/tmp/ezstream.log &" from rc.local. That should give you a log file in /tmp - beware /tmp gets wiped on reboot, so it will only contain the latest. Also disable this once you have it working.

Comment: @TBR Thanks a lot! It was my fail, I setup relative path to the playlist in the ezstream_mp3.xml. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my fail. If anyone will have this problem, check your ezstream_mp3.xml, you should have full path to your playlist instead of relative path.